# Using Node v4.0 for Windows Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, azure

I am building a web app using Node. I started when version 4.0 of Node came out. When I run `node -v` on my local machine, I see: "v4.0.0". I deployed the site as a Microsoft Azure Web App. However, that introduced a 500 error.

I looked at the logs, and I see the following:

```
Wed Sep 23 2015 13:29:20 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Unaught exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\routes\index.js:4:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

The line in question uses the `class` keyword, which is allowed in Node 4.0. That prompted me to check the version of node running in my Azure Web App. From the console in Azure, I ran, `node -v` again. Now I see, "v0.10.32".

How do I get Node 4.0 running for a Microsoft Azure Web App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

specify the version in your "engines" directive in package.json

```
{
  "engines":{"node":4.0.0}
}
```

more info about specifying versions here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-specify-node-version-azure-apps/

Comment: Wow! That saved me a LOT of time. I was going down a totally different route. Thanks for your help.